# How do I add records from an Access database into an existing SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an existing Access database that has out grown it's usefulness. I have written a Visual Basic program that uses a SQL Server database and have been re-entering the data from the Access file into SQL Server individually.

I still have 300+ records to move and would like to find a way to do all this using either a data snippet in Visual Basic, or using SQL Server Express. I'm smart enough to set up and use Access, and smart enough to create a program and database in Visual Basic and SQL Server but for some reason I not smart enough to move the records between the 2 databases.

When I originally created the `.mdf` file I attempted to move the records at that time but everything I tried didn't work so I figured I'd get it later, but now I have 300+ records in the `.mdf` file and need to get the others moved over. Anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Yes you can. Search for MSSQL ODBC on how to set it up.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest thing to do is create your database, then in SSMS's Object Explorer, right click on the database, Tasks -> Import Data ... and go through the Import/Export wizard, selecting MS Access as your source.

Comment: Greg, I attempted to do that when I first created the SQL database and it did nothing, no data import, no message why not. So I, in retrospect, made my first mistake by entering new records into the SQL database thinking that using SQL I'd be able to transfer the ACCESS data later. I have tried, but can't seem to open both databases at the same time in SQL. The one thing I haven't tried is opening the ACCESS file, reading the data into a dataset then closing the ACCESS file, open the SQL file and write the dataset into it. I'm not sure how to do this, or if it's even possible.

Comment: what version of Access and SQL do you have?  If Access is less than version 2013, then there should be some kind of upsizing wizard in Access that may help you export from access and import to SQL. Regarding "it did nothing", i really don't know what you did or didn't do, so can't help there.

Comment: And there is also SQL Server Migration Assistant.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssma/archive/2014/08/21/latest-update-microsoft-sql-server-migration-assistant-ssma-v6-0-is-now-available.aspx